# Move multiple files to multiple to multiple directories

Tags: linux, xargs, mv

I have 5 files called file1.txt, file2.txt ... file5.txt and I would like to move each one into a respective directory called dir1, dir2 ... dir5.

So file1.txt is moved into dir1, file2.txt is moved into dir2 and so on.

Is there a way to do this in one line at the command line, using `mv` and `xargs` perhaps?

I'm only suggesting `xargs` because I quite like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195655/how-to-copy-a-file-to-multiple-directories-using-the-gnu-cp-command/195972#195972) provided by Robert Gamble to a question asking how to copy one file to multiple directories.

`echo dir1 dir2 dir3 | xargs -n 1 cp file1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally prefer a solution that relies on a `for` loop, e.g.:

```
for n in {1..5}; do echo mv -- "file$n.txt" "dir$n/"; done
#                   ^^^^ remove that
```

This can be done with `xargs` but I find the solution to be less elegant:

```
seq 1 5 | xargs -n1 -I{} echo mv -- "file{}.txt" "dir{}/"
#                        ^^^^ remove that
```

Comment: That works, thanks! I didn't think about using `echo` to see what commands would actually be executed before executing for real - I'll keep that in mind.

Is there a way to use your solution on files name fileA, fileB etc.?

Comment: Just do `for n in A B ...; do ...`. Also, the `echo` was meant to help me debug it. I accidentately left it there :-). I'm glad that it helped.

Comment: Thanks for the `xargs` addition. With regard to the fileA, fileB etc. question. I can't see how provide the command with 2 inputs. The following `for n in {A..E}; do echo mv -- "file$n.txt" "dir$n"; done` would mv fileA.txt to dirA and so on, but if I wanted to move fileA.txt to dir1 - Is that possible or is that a different question entirely?

Comment: For that I would say it's a different question. You could probably do it with something like `mv -- "file$n.txt" "dir$(($(LC_CTYPE=C printf '%d' "'$n")-64))"` where `$n` is the capital letter, but the requirements are not entirely clear.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could do it, if it weren't necessarily a list of consecutive integers, and `dir*` didn't necessarily already exist.

```sh
for f in *.txt; do mkdir dir${f: -5:1}; mv $f dir${f: -5:1}/; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Parallel you would so:

```
parallel mv {} {=s/file/dir/=} ::: *.txt
```