# Need a script that copies a single file to multiple directories

Tags: bash

I'm stuck with this script and would like some help on the same!

I want to make a folder called "upload" which will contain a script that copies a `.jar` file from there to multiple directories (See below)

```
/home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/EUSim1
/home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/EUSim2
/home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/EUSim3
```

and so on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy a file to multiple directories using the gnu cp command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195655/how-to-copy-a-file-to-multiple-directories-using-the-gnu-cp-command)

Comment: _would like some help with a script_. Which script? You haven't posted any script.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple script: 
How to use it

1. `touch simpleScript.sh`
2. `vim simpleScript.sh`
3. Copy/Paste the line below
4. Update `TRX_SOURCE_PATH`, `DEST_PATH`, `DEST_PATH1`, `DEST_PATH2`
5. Save
6. `chmod +x ./simpleScript.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

TRX_SOURCE_PATH='/Path/Test.pdf'
DEST_PATH='/Path/Test'
DEST_PATH1='/Path/Test1'
DEST_PATH2='/Path/Test2'

echo "Starting copy"
echo "Destination:" $DEST_PATH
cp $TRX_SOURCE_PATH $DEST_PATH

echo "copy done for folder:" $DEST_PATH

echo "Destination:" $DEST_PATH1
cp $TRX_SOURCE_PATH $DEST_PATH1

echo "copy done for folder:" $DEST_PATH1

echo "Destination:" $DEST_PATH2
cp $TRX_SOURCE_PATH $DEST_PATH2

echo "copy done for folder:" $DEST_PATH2
echo "All Copy done"
```

Hope this script helps you .

Comment: `Echo`? Uppercase?

Answer (score 1):

A Quick Script, for reference:

script

```
#!/bin/bash

inputfile=$1

for var in "$@"
do
    if [[ $2 == $3 ]];then
    exit 1
    fi    
    cp -v $inputfile $2
    shift
done
```

Command

```
./script simple.jar                                     \
 /home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/EUSim1/simple.jar   \
 /home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/EUSim2/simple.jar   \
 /home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/EUSim3/simple.jar   \
```

Output

```
 'simple.jar' -> '/home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/EUSim1/simple.jar'
 'simple.jar' -> '/home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/EUSim2/simple.jar'
 'simple.jar' -> '/home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/EUSim3/simple.jar'
```

This is a simple script. you can do little tweaks and add --prefix or make the script read the input from a file.

(or)
use cp with xargs:

```
echo dir1 dir2 dir3 | xargs -n 1 cp file
```