# Why I get the "omitting directory" error using globbing in cp command?

Tags: linux, cp, glob

I'm trying to copy the "file.txt" file into all the directories.

```
[root@mycomputer]# ls -lh
total 132K
drwxr--r--.  2 postgres postgres 4.0K Jan  2 08:47 ilo01
drwxr--r--.  2 postgres postgres 4.0K Jan  2 08:40 ilo02
drwxr--r--.  2 postgres postgres 4.0K Jan  2 08:40 ilo03
drwxr--r--.  2 postgres postgres 4.0K Jan  2 08:40 ilo04
drwxr--r--.  2 postgres postgres 4.0K Jan  2 08:40 ilo05
drwxr--r--.  2 postgres postgres 4.0K Jan  2 08:40 ilo06
drwxr--r--.  2 postgres postgres 4.0K Jan  2 08:40 ilo07
drwxr--r--.  2 postgres postgres 4.0K Jan  2 08:40 ilo08
drwxr--r--.  2 postgres postgres 4.0K Jan  2 10:03 ilo09
drwxr--r--. 11 postgres postgres 4.0K Jan  2 11:15 ilo10
-rw-r--r--.  1 postgres postgres  64K Jun 27  2016 file.txt
```

Using TAB to see the behaviour of the command to run:

```
[root@mycomputer]# cp -p file.txt ilo[0-1][0-9]
ilo01/ ilo02/ ilo03/ ilo04/ ilo05/ ilo06/ ilo07/ ilo08/ ilo09/ ilo10/
```

But I get this error:

```
[root@mycomputer]# cp -v -p file.txt ilo[0-1][0-9]*
`postgresTdas.txt' -> `ilo10/file.txt'
cp: omitting directory `ilo01'
cp: omitting directory `ilo02'
cp: omitting directory `ilo03'
cp: omitting directory `ilo04'
cp: omitting directory `ilo05'
cp: omitting directory `ilo06'
cp: omitting directory `ilo07'
cp: omitting directory `ilo08'
cp: omitting directory `ilo09'
```

Same thing happens with:

```
[root@mycomputer]# cp -p file.txt ilo*
```

and

```
[root@mycomputer]# cp -p file.txt ilo*/
```

I don't understand why "[0-1][0-9] doen't work the way I need.

I'm assuming that the copy is going to put the file.txt in the list that the TAB shows.

What am I missing?

Comment: `cp` can copy a one or more files into a single target directory or it can copy a file to a single target file.  It can't copy a single file to more than one target.  You need to create a loop to copy your file to all those directories.

Comment: You can find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195655/how-to-copy-a-file-to-multiple-directories-using-the-gnu-cp-command

Comment: Thanks. I'm really ashamed about this question   : /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most implementations of the `cp` command are *not* able to copy to multiple targets. Nothing you can do about that. You need to work around that limitation calling `cp` multiple times. Easiest probably is something like that:

```
ls -d dir* | xargs -n 1 cp file.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

The arguments expand to the file + all the directories

`cp` considers the last argument as the target, so the other directories are considered as sources.

And because `cp` won't copy directories unless `-r` or `-R` option is set (copy directory *and* contents), you get the warnings on all directories but the last one.

I'd do that with a bash/sh script instead:

```
for d in ilo[0-1][0-9]
do
   cp -p file.txt $d
done
```

Comment: I god, I made a bubu. All the answers are correct. I give it to arkascha the acceptance because he responded it first. But thank you so much.

Comment: 46 minutes ago against 55 minutes ago? I responded first. But do as you wish. You're the boss :)