# Copying a file into multiple directories in bash

Tags: bash

I have a file I would like to copy into about 300,000 different directories, these are themselves split between two directories, e.g.

```
DirA/Dir001/
...
DirB/Dir149000/
```

However when I try:

```
 cp file.txt */*
```

It returns:

```
bash: /bin/cp: Argument list too long
```

What is the best way of copying a file into multiple directories, when you have too many to use cp?

Comment: Why on earth do you want to make 300,000 copies of a Python script file?? Please explain in more detail what problem you are attempting to solve; there is almost certainly a better way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy a file to multiple directories using the gnu cp command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195655/how-to-copy-a-file-to-multiple-directories-using-the-gnu-cp-command)

Comment: Only one argument to `cp` can be a destination directory; `cp one two three` will copy `one` and `two` to `three`, overwriting the copy of `one`.

Comment: @tripleee I have edited, as to why, basically the python script needs to be in the same directory as the file it's working on!

Comment: @Manuel: Not a duplicate; OP has already figured out that `cp` cannot do that and is asking for *alternatives* to it -- and the answers to that linked question are *atrociously* bad. (`echo` or `ls` piped to `xargs`? *Really?* One space in a filename and your "solution" breaks...)

Comment: @Neosage: Then it is best to use a link like in the second example of DevSolar, that way if you update it in one place you don't need to copy it everywhere again.

Comment: @Neosage: Yours is what we call a "XY problem". You are asking to solve problem Y, which you only *have* because of problem X. You *should* be asking us to solve problem X (that script of yours requiring to be in the same directory as the files it operates on). Perhaps in a different question? ;-)

Comment: Okay, I have edited accordingly to make it more appropriate for the website and for future users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extrapolating from the answer to [your other question](/q/51150128) you seem to have code which looks something like

```
for TGZ in $(find . -name "file.tar.gz")
do
    mkdir -p work
    cd work
    tar xzf $TGZ
    python script.py
    cd ..
    rm -rf work
done
```

Of course, the trivial fix is to replace

```
python script.py
```

with

```
python ../script.py
```

and voilá, you no longer need a copy of the script in each directory at all.

I woud further advice to refactor out the `cd` and changing `script.py` so you can pass it the directory to operate on as a command-line argument. (Briefly, `import sys` and examine the value of `sys.argv[1]` though you'll often want to have option parsing and support for multiple arguments; `argparse` from the Python standard library is slightly intimidating, but there are friendly third-party wrappers like `click`.)

As an aside, many beginners seem to think the location of your executable is going to be the working directory when it executes. This is obviously not the case; or `/bin/ls` woul only list files in `/bin`.

To get rid of the `cd` problem mentioned in a comment, a minimal fix is

```
for tgz in $(find . -name "file.tar.gz")
do
    mkdir -p work
    tar -C work -x -z -f "$tgz"
    (cd work; python ../script.py)
    rm -rf work
done
```

Again, if you can change the Python script so it doesn't need its input files in the current directory, this can be simplified further. Notice also the preference for lower case for your variables, and the use of quoting around variables which contain file names. The use of `find` in a command substitution is still slightly broken (it can't work for file names which contain whitespace or shell metacharacters) but maybe that's a topic for a separate question.

Comment: unfortunately I'm running into this problem: `gzip: ./archaea/GCF_900111935.1/GCF_900111935.1_IMG-taxon_2617270732_annotated_assembly_protein.faa.gz: No such file or directory`

When running the script: `for GZ in $(find . -name "*.gz")
do
    mkdir -p work
    cd work
    gunzip $GZ
    python3 ../propgenfromproteome.py
    cd ..
    rm -rf work
done`

I don't really understand as those files definitely exist!

Edit: I am working on a v2 which uses sys, but I feel it may be a lot of reworking for this particular script

Comment: The `cd` is precisely the problem here; the loop is receiving file names relative to the directory before the `cd`.

Comment: So is the solution essentially to rewrite the script?

Answer (score 3):

The answer to the question as asked is `find`.

```
find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -exec cp script.py {} \;
```

But of course @triplee is right... why make so many copies of a file?

You *could*, of course, instead create *links* to the file...

```
find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -exec ln script.py {} \;
```

The options `-mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2` limit the recursive search of `find` to elements *exactly* two levels deep from the current directory (`.`). The `-type d` matches all directories. `-exec` then executes the command (up to the closing `\;`), for each element found, replacing the `{}` with the name of the element (the two-levels-deep subdirectory).

The links created are **hard links**. That means, you edit the script in one place, the script will look different in *all* places. The script is, for all intents and purposes, *in all the places*, with none of them being any less "real" than the others. (This concept can be surprising to those not used to it.) Use `ln -s` if you instead want to create "soft" links, which are mere references to "the one, true" `script.py` in the original location.

The beauty of `find ... -exec ... {}`, as opposed to many other ways to do it, is that it will work correctly even for filenames with "funny" characters in them, including but not limited to spaces or newlines.

---

But still, you should really only need *one* script. You should fix the part of your project where you need that script in every directory; *that* is the broken part...