# How to copy multiple file to Single directory using the gnu cp command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a scenario wherein various files have been organized by tagging them with a `yyyymmdd` directly in the filename. It is the opposite of the case in this answered thread, [How to copy a file to multiple directories using the gnu cp command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195655)

I would like to move all the matching files to their respectively named `yyyy` folder

The files are structured as follows:

```
/dir_1/a/bcd_20210223.txt
/dir_1/b/cde_20220512.txt
/dir_1/c/def_20220223.txt
/dir_1/d/efg_20230824.txt
/dir_1/f/ghi_20220732.txt
```

My first test is that I switch to `dir_1` folder and look for any matching files from 2022 and there are 3

```
echo ./*/*2022*
```

When this is executed on the command line:

```
echo ./*/*2022* | xargs -n 1 cp -R 2022/
```

The following message comes up:

```
cp: ./b/cde_20220512.txt: Not a directory
cp: ./c/def_20220223.txt: Not a directory
cp: ./f/ghi_20220732.txt: Not a directory
```

Is this a quick fix, not sure if I have to put together a tiny script maybe with a loop?

Comment: what do you think `cp -R 2022/ ./b/cde_20220512.txt` should do?

Comment: copy contents of that folder (while preserving the structure) to that specified target location

Comment: re-read the `cp` manpage synopsis, or rather think about whether that matches what you state you wish to do

Comment: also, what do you mean by "I would like to move"? `cp` does not "move" files; you need `mv` for that

Comment: btw, note that `./*/*2022*` matches `./q/xyz_20120228.txt`

Comment: Use `cp -t`: `cp -t 2022/ -- ./*/*2022*`.  Note that I omitted the unnecessary `-R` and use of `echo` and `xargs`.  Unless you suspect the number of files and the four static arguments might exceed ARG_MAX, you don't need to use `xargs`.  Your command also fails with filenames having spaces.

Comment: The second argument for `cp` (the destination) is what xargs spills out, i.e. _b/cde_20220512.txt_, which most likely is a text file. Hence you ask to recursively copy the directory `2022` to a text file. This obviously does not make sense. IMO, it is easier for debugging if you don't use `xargs` here, but just loop over your files.